# How to implement Google analytics for cross selling?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to implement

1. People who viewed this also viewed that.

Using Google Analytics on a custom built website in PHP?

This isin't a duplicate, its a part of that question since its too broad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement cross selling on a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840990/how-to-implement-cross-selling-on-a-website)

Comment: Hi Philippe, thats my question and its too broad, thats why i asked just a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path analysis:

> Path Analysis
>
> Are there paths through your site that are more popular than others,
>   and if so, are those the paths you want traffic to follow? You may
>   have a path in mind for your users like Home Page > Product Page >
>   Shopping Cart > Checkout, but you may uncover a more popular path like
>   Home > Product > Search > Search Results > Search > Search Results >
>   exit. That unexpected path can indicate things like users not finding
>   products they want, or your internal search not returning results that
>   are helpful.

Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1713056?hl=en